# iOS: How do I synchronize my managedObjectContext when using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)?

Tags: ios, xml, ios5, xml-parsing, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using the following code to run a function that parses my xml files...

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("updateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://path/to/file.xml"]; } ); 
dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://path/to/file1.xml"]; } );
dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://path/to/file2.xml"]; } );
dispatch_async(queue,^ { [self updateFromXMLFile:@"http://path/to/file3.xml"]; } );

dispatch_barrier_async(queue,^ {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ { 
            [self setBottomBarToUpdated]; 
    });
});
```

Here below is the function `updateFromXMLFile`:

```
- (BOOL) updateFromXMLFile:(NSString *)pathToFile {

         NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pathToFile];
         NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

         XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

         parser.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

         [xmlParser setDelegate: parser];

         BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

         if(success)
              return TRUE;
         else
              return FALSE;

}
```

The problem I'm coming across is this error message: `***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0xc675e10> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

I'm guessing that it has something to do with all the processes messing with my ManagedObjectContext at the same time. I'm not sure how to handle that though. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: strongly recommend reviewing the WWDC 2012 session on Core Data, they cover all this threading stuff

Comment: Did you try commenting one of the four dispatch calls to check if any of them specifically is creating the problem? I would start there. Also, is there a way you can serialize the parsing? Did you think of NSOperationQueue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the code for how your XMLParser handles its delegate responsibilities, because that's what's being called.

Now, you are parsing multiple files at the same time, from within separate threads.  They are all calling into different XMLParser objects, but each of those is using the same managed object context (MOC).

If you are using the default MOC setup, you need to reconvene all those MOC calls to the main thread (if that is, indeed where you first created your context).  If you use confinement, and your MOC is not created on the main thread, then you are giving yourself more trouble.

However, it's a pretty simple fix.  In that parser delegate method, whenever you use the managed object context, enclose it in a call to dispatch that part on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Put your code that accesses the MOC in here.
});
```

Now, for doing bulk downloads into Core Data, you are probably better off using one of two approaches.

Create a new MOC, attached directly to the persistent store coordinator, and do all your saving there.  Your main MOC needs to observe Save notifications and merge those changes.

Or, make the new MOC be a child of your main MOC, and save directly into it, then it can save.

If, however, your managed object context is of either NSMainQueueConcurrencyType or NSPrivateQueueConcurrency type (only way to do second option above), then you can just use its perfromBlock method...

```
[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    // Do your MOC stuff in here
}];
```

The bottom line is that a MOC can be created with one of three concurrency types.  If it is NSConfinementConcurrencyType, then you must not touch it outside the thread in which it was created.  If it is NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, you have to use performBlock* or only touch it in the main thread.  If it is NSPrivateConcurrencyType, you must use performBlock*.

Comment: the parse file is way too big I would think to put on here. I need to clean it up ;/ -- However, my ManagedObjectContext is of type `NSManagedObjectContext` and I have 4 different subclasses of `NSManagedObject` for each object type I'm parsing. The only places I think I access the MOC are at the @synthesize, [appDelegate saveContext] calls for each of the four object types once im closing the library element of the xml files, and I think that's it. I tried your 1st suggestion but didn't seem to work still got the error ;/

Comment: You CAN NOT access a managed object context in any manner you like.  Core Data has very strict rules that must be followed.  Any time you do ANYTHING with a MOC (which includes the managed objects it contains) you must obey the rules.  I summarized them in the answer I provided.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot use a concurrent queue to interface to a MOC, you have to use a serial one. Change your queue creation to

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("updateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and all will be well. Again, the reason for doing this is that the final XMLParser objects are concurrently trying to interact with the moc.

Your options are dictated by what XMLParser (or any class) is doing. If a class does its heavy lifting BEFORE it interacts with the MOC, or it downloads data from the web, then you would gain something by concurrency.

What I would suggest you do is download the data you need from the URLS, then serially work with the MOC. You must interact with the MOC on a single thread (in iOS) but that does NOT have to be the mainThread - it can be any thread as long as its just the one. This means that if you create your own serial queue, everything has to be done on that queue including creating the MOC!

Back to your code. Lets assume that you do all Core Data work on the mainQueue (for now). The solution is change your code to this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0) {
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pathToFile];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
  XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
  parser.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
  [xmlParser setDelegate: parser];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

         // need some means to associate success/failure with the URL
  } );
```

You do as much as you can concurrently, the serialize when hitting the MOC. The only difference when you use a serial queue for the MOC is that your would message that queue instead of the mainQueue.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem with the concurrent queue.  The files are processed using completely separate objects.  The only issue is with the MOC, and that would be an issue even with a serial queue, because it's always an issue anytime you access a MOC from multiple thread.

Comment: What I did in my code was to use concurrent operations to process data, then access to the moc was done on the serial queue. The point is that your error is due to concurrent access of the moc. This also got all moc work in its own thread (since the serial queue is off the main thread).

Comment: Anyway you could update your answer to describe a little more into what you are saying in your latest comment? Not sure I follow... do you not use blocks for the individual method calls?